# Оптимизировать iframe внутри HTML

Tags: javascript, html, оптимизация

Есть раздел сайта полон видео что грузит браузер. Я скрыл эти ролики `display: none;` и при наведении мышью отображаю. Но нагрузка практически не уменьшилась. Что можно предпринять в данной ситуации? Может как-то кешировать при помощи javascript? Допустим полностью удалить `iframe` с кода сайта, а при наведении уже заново подгружать код?

Comment: `src="about:blank"`, при наведении мышью - устанавливать нужный `src`

Comment: если вкратце сказать - то посмотрите как это устроено на youtube видео разбивают на фрагменты но в самом начале самого видео нету а на странице лишь приевьюшка - которая ffmpeg генерирует на лету и сначало показывают превью потом при клике на эту превьюшку запускается видео не полностью а фрагментами - кусочками xhr

Comment: @UbuntuUser я понимаю но внутри движка изменить не получится, страница генерируется с десятком видео, и как-то средствами JS/CSS нужно их оптимизировать.

Comment: вы вместо видео положите превьюшки - а при клике на превью показывайте видео - вы же согласитесь что те же гифки будут вразы шустрее грузиться чем видео хотя бы весом 300мгб ....образно говоря у вас на странице не должно быть видео а ссылки на него должны быть в базе или в json где не будь

Comment: @UbuntuUser сейчас после загрузки страницы все видео скрываются, и делается привью. При наведении мыши ролик отображается, но как я понял если ifram'ы есть на странице даже под display none они несут нагрузку, и тут я не знаю что делать.

Comment: нет нет ...display:none не убирают фактически сам контент а оишь меняют его отображение - вообще уберите видео а оставьте тег img внутри любого тега а по клику по тегу показывайте ваш iframe собствено всё

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае всё просто, нужно удалить IFRAME с сайта перед этим получив идентификатор  каждого видео.

Далее создаёте привью изображения при помощи данной ссылки -

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/'+VIDEO_ID+'/maxresdefault.jpg
```

И отображаете вместо старых роликов.

Там же добавляете кнопку при нажатии которой будет открываться IFRAME с видео, ID которых вы получили раннее а так же закрываться предыдущий.

И так на сайте не будет более одного ролика для просмотра так как каждый будет подгружаться индивидуально что существенно снизит нагрузку.